# Find average based on if cell is included in mapping tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to find the following Average, or even a Sum, based on if the value located in the column would return a TRUE in a vlookup.

[image]

So in the above example, I'm looking to find the average and sum for apple and orange, based on me looking it up based on the word test.

Comment: What is your excel version? What result do you expect from provided sample? Show your result manually so that we can do it by formula?

Answer (score 1):

For average try-

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:B4,MMULT(--(D2:G4="Test"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D2:G4)))))
```

For sum try-

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B4,MMULT(--(D2:G4="Test"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D2:G4)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work actually. This formula basically assumed everything is on the same row. I'm essentially wanting to look up the SUM for Apple and Orange, but only because Test is next to it. And Apple and Orange will be on a different tab. Columns D:E are essentially mapping. Column A won't have anything next to it.

Answer (score 0):

For Larger Data you may need this.

[image: Formula Lookup]